# Wrapping promise in async/await

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-next

I'm struggling a bit with async/await and returning a value from a Promise.

```
function test () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('Hello')
  })
} 

async function c() {
  await test()
}
```

As I understood things I should be able to get a value by doing:

```
console.log(c())
```

But clearly I am missing a point here as this returns a promise.  Shouldn't it print "hello"? On a similar note I am unclear as to whether a callback needs to be converted to a promise before wrapping it in async/await?

Comment: well, no, async/await doesn't magically make asynchronous code run synchronously. Code outside of the async function still has to wait for the async function to complete.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I am missing a point here as this returns a promise. Shouldn't `console.log(c())` print "hello"?

No, `async` functions always return promises. They're not magically running asynchronous code synchronously - rather the reverse, they turn synchronous-looking code (albeit speckled with `await` keywords) into asynchronously running one.

You can get the result value *inside* the asynchronous function:

```
async function c() {
  const result = await test()
  console.log(result);
  return 'World';
}
c().then(console.log);
```

> I am unclear as to whether a callback needs to be converted to a promise before wrapping it in async/await?

Yes, you can `await` only promises. See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for how to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

> Async functions return a Promise. If the function throws an error, the
>   Promise will be rejected. If the function returns a value, the Promise
>   will be resolved.

Comment: you should specify the source